# Как задать 2 границы?

Tags: html, css

Привет. Нужно блоку задать 2 бордера, но они разного цвета и имеют скругления. Метод вложенных блоков оставим на плохой конец, думаю про :before тоже. outline и box-shadow здесь, видимо, тоже не подойдут (они вроде не поддерживают скругления).

Comment: А почему box-shadow не подходит? Задвайте четвертый параметр равный ширине бордюра и цвет. Нормально тени скругляются :)

Comment: ДА?Не знал...Надеюсь pie потянет

Comment: atnartur мне простительно!!1
Сypher делай ответом.Будем +
У меня бажок от pie .Весь блок окрашивается со цветом тени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fm8Td - поэксперементируйте с параметрами

```
<div>test</div>​
```

-

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 5px;

    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red,
          inset 0 0 0 5px blue  
    ; 
}
​
```